# Refactoring a Java project causes hundreds of "X not public" errors

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation, java-7, visibility

I'm busy upgrading an ancient java app, and after getting it compiling I set about reorganizing the code structure. There are currently 500 files in ONE massive folder, so I need to split it into a neater folder structure. The moment I moved some files, the compiler generates heaps of `"X() is not public in <BaseClass>"` errors. Yes, the refactoring tool added package statements and imports to both sides,

Apparently every class has all its members with implicit visibility, ie:

```
 void setSelection(int x){...}
```

Apart from manually adding visibility attributes, is there a faster way to resolve the mess with less editing?

```
 public void setSelection(int x){...} /// Yay! only 5000 more occurrences to go!
```

Comment: you can use eclipse ide for the purpose of refactoring , are you using the same?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans and it has some basic support for refactoring. However the project WAS compiling when all files were in one folder. The moment I start to organize, these errors are generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should fix this by hand.  For each class and class member make a judgment as to whether the access *should* be `public`, `protected`, `private` or package private.  Creating / fixing modularity and abstraction boundaries is not something that I would trust to a dumb tool.

Yes, if you have hundreds of error message, you have lots of things to correct.  But the end result will be better quality code ... than if you blindly changed all package private to stuff to `public`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a search-replace with NetBeans by using regex.
I don't know very well Netbeans but I know that it's possible and with eclipse it's rather good.
Hint : watch previews before validating the replacement.

For example in your case, you could use it :

```
    search regex = (^[^\n\w]*void\s.*$)
    replacement = public $0
```

If you have other things that "void" as return of your methods, you could replace "void" by a expression more relevant for your return types.